# Как сделать чтобы если текст не умещается в блок по ширине появлялись точки?

Tags: css

[image]
Должны быть точки после текста, если он не умещается по ширине.

Answer (score 0):

-webkit-line-clamp: 2; отвечает за количество отображаемых строк

```css
 overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: initial;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
```